# Accepting a graduate program. Enrollment in two graduate programs? Transferring Universities

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, transfer-student, covid-19

I work at University A. I applied to UA's MA program and was accepted. It starts in the summer. Because I already work for UA, my MA is funded and I've already taken several classes at non-degree status that feed into UA's MA program (I'll add, I don't have a contract saying I need to work for a certain period to have my MA funded. Unlike many corporate jobs, my tuition assistance is just a clean and simple benefit for me.) I accepted UA because that's just the next step. If I take any more non-degree courses, they don't count towards my MA and for the foreseeable future i'll be working at UA unless I get a job at UB.

I also applied to UB in my hometown because it's more aligned with my interests and is a full-time program and I want to be closer to my mother. UB starts in the fall but I HAVE to find funding to go there. I can't afford to move, loose my job and pay for full-time tuition. I am currently waiting to hear back on job opportunities at UB that would pay for my tuition. I've asked UB what the repercussions of submitting my intent to enroll and not enrolling would be and their response was basically, "whatever, you'll loose your $$$ deposit." My concern is not, "what if I can't go there" my concern is, "what if I  DO decide enroll in UB and they have an unforeseen problem with the fact that i'm already enrolled at UA through my current job).

**Should I just ask UB what their policy is if someone is already enrolled?**

**Should I contact UA and let them know there's a possibility i'll need to relocate?** Ideally, I wish I could just defer UB and then transfer if I get a job  but that's just not how the registration timeline works. **So, what should my next step be to minimize impact?**

**Should I just just intend to enroll in both programs and cross this bridge when I actually have to register?** I'm seeing a lot of negative feedback about this on other posts but people need to realize these are professional Masters programs. They're good programs but we're not talking PhD programs with tons of people waitlisted. From my perspective these are businesses that want your money and enrollment. UA will be online... I don't think they denied people they wanted to attend. And UB was reported as having been under-enrolled.... I know I can't know these things for sure; so, i'm not giving myself a pass for it but just to frame the situation a bit.  I do anticipate enrolling in both programs if timing works that way... I'm just letting the unknown make me feel really guilty about it.

Comment: Are you sure you can enroll in two programs at once, under their own rules? Furthermore, is it really possible to complete two master's while working (full-time?)?

Comment: Why do you want to enroll in two master's? Why not just do them sequentially?

Comment: I think how I would handle this is by asking UB what the consequences for late enrollment are. I agree that there are not any major ethics issues here, just the issue of not losing your deposit, etc.